# Calculate difference between two dates returns a negative number

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to calculate how many days there are between different dates. Like the topic says, I'm getting a negative value. I guess I could just take the absolute value, but the fact that it returns a negative value, makes me doubt if the calculations are correct. Below is my code:

```
DateTime previousDay = new DateTime(1998, 6, 31, new GregorianCalender());
DateTime nextDay = new DateTime(1998, 6, 3, new GregorianCalender());

TimeSpan differenceInDays = (nextDay - previousDay); 
double xAxisValue = differenceInDays.TotalDays;
```

Ofcourse 3-31 gives -28, but since we want it to show days between, it makes no sense that it doesn't return a positive value. Am I doing something wrong?

I also tried this approach:

```
(a - b).TotalDays
```

where a and b are of type Datime

Comment: Just do a `Math.Abs` on the number and move on with your life ;-)

Comment: Seriously? Just take the `Abs()` and everything will be fine.

Comment: Or make sure next day is later than previous day ;)

Comment: What is your altitude when the calculation happens?

Comment: ``.TotalDays`` is returning the expected result. You are expecting it to return the difference in days, hence the ``differenceInDays`` variable name, but that's just not what it calculates.

Comment: How is it possible that the `nextDay` is 28 days earlier? :)

Answer (score 13):

> I guess I could just take the absolute value, but the fact that it returns a negative value, makes me doubt if the calculations are correct.

Why? `nextDay` is earlier than `previousDay`, so of course subtracting `previousDay` will give a negative result.

You're effectively asking "How many days do I need to add to `previousDay` in order to get to `nextDay`? The answer is -28.

What *does* concern me is the names here - I'd expect a `nextDay` value to always be later than a `previousDay` value - so either the way you're finding those values is incorrect, or you need to change the names to make the meaning clearer. Presumably they're not "next" and "previous" in respect to the same context.

Answer (score 9):

This is **expected behavior**.

You should use the **TimeSpan.Duration()** method.

It returns a new TimeSpan object whose value is the absolute value of the current TimeSpan object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I think this is because of there is no '1998-06-31' date in the calendar.

Comment: Well in fact it probably DOES exist in his calendar becuase he doesn't say anything about any exceptions.

Comment: +1 for your catch, but even if the date is 1998-06-30, the difference would be `-27` days. Negative.

Answer (score 2):

> Ofcourse 3-31 gives -28, but since we want it to show days between, it makes no sense that it doesn't return a positive value. Am I doing something wrong?

I think that you don't know which date is greater before hand.And your naming is just confusing.

You can first check which date is greater and then subtract the Lesser from the greater

```
TimeSpan differenceInDays;
double xAxisValue;
if(nextDay > previousDay )
{
    differenceInDays = (nextDay - previousDay); 
}
else
{
    differenceInDays = (previousDay - nextDay); 
}
xAxisValue = differenceInDays.TotalDays;
```